# Calculating the set of computers infected by malware, in a network of communicating computers?

Tags: c, algorithm, graph-algorithm, greedy, minimum-spanning-tree

A little backstory: It has been a really long time since I've coded in C (a year. Jumping back into this is really overwhelming.

I need some advice on implementation. **Could someone could explain how you would go about designing this? I understand the concept of the problem, but feel lost as to how to even start implementation.**

Here are the constraints:

**The Input (Given to the algorithm):**

1. The number of computers in the network, designated as N. Assume that the computers are named 1, 2.. up to N.
2. A log consisting of a list of triples (C1, C2, t). In each triple, C1 and C2 are computer names and t is a timestamp.  If (C1, C2, t) appears in the log, then it means that C1 and C2 communicated with each other at time t. (t will always be an integer >= to 0)
3. There is a computer, CBad, which is the name of the computer where the malware was first introduced. There is also a timestamp, tBad, which is time at which malware was introduced in CBad.

**Mechanics of Infection:**

1. If a computer, say C0, is infected and another computer, C1 communicates with C0 at time t, then C will also become infected. (and it will become infected at time t.)
2. If a computer is infected at time t, then it is infected at any time t1>=t (in other words, it is considered infected at that point and any point afterwards)

The expected output here is a txt file displaying a list of the infected computers as a result of CBad (our patient 0) being infected at time tBad.

We've been discussing minimum spanning tree algorithms (specifically Prims and Kruskals) **I'm pretty sure he wants use one of these in solving this problem.**

Thoughts so far: 
My theory so far is that in each list of triplets, C1 and C2 represent two vertices that make up an edge. And the timestamp t represents the cost/weight/whatever of that edge.  Somehow I have to build a connected, undirected graph and then run (Kruskal's algorithm?) to find the set?... I just don't know.  I feel like an idiot here. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking things. While it's possible to represent part of the scenario as a directed graph, that representation doesn't seem to lend itself to any useful optimizations here. (Particularly because `t` doesn't represent anything with weight-like behavior.) Instead, consider a straightforward approach:

- Initialize a set S of nodes (representing the "infected" computers) to contain only `CBad`.
- Remove all triples from your list that have `t < tBad`.
- Sort the remaining triples by `t`.
- For each triple `(C1, C2, t)` in your newly sorted list:

  - If `C1` is in `S`, add `C2` to `S`.
- Return the contents of `S`.

This is `O(n log n)`, as we had to sort the list. There might be some clever way to make it `O(n)`, but I kind of doubt it.

Comment: +1 exactly what i had in mind to write. side note: the infection direction in the question is other-wise, as in`if(C2 in S) S.Add(C1)`. but if infections are two-way?" then you need both.